# .Net razor - While using @Model.Variable name in window.onload - throws reference error

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, razor

I am using ASP.NET Core with Razor.
I have a page `Education.cshtml` and `Education.cshtml.cs`.

In `Education.cshtml.cs` `OnGet()` handler I am assigning a value to a variable. And in `.cshtml` file I am trying to access the variable using `@Model.variable` during `window.onload`. Using it inside `window.onLoad` JavaScript because I have to call a JavaScript function with this variable as parameter after the page loads.

But I get an reference error saying:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: "variablevalue" is not defined
> at **window.onload**

How to fix this Below is my code.

In Education.cshtml.cs :

```cs
[BindProperty]
public string degree { get; set; }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
{
    degree = "XYZ";
}
```

In `Education.cshtml`:

```
@if (Model.EducationDetails?.successful == true)
{
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        <h4>Deatils</h4>
        <hr>
        <strong>@Model.Education.StudentNumber</strong>
     </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
         console.log('Model degree value -' + @Model.degree );
        // callJavascriptFunction(@Model.degree); // Need to pass this @Model.degree to JS function
            };
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of your property is a string use double or single quotes:

```js
console.log('Model degree value -' + '@Model.degree');
```

or

```js
console.log('Model degree value -' + "@Model.degree");
```

Comment: You are welcome! By the way the `"` character should work too for this case.